# Access delete query: keep only most recent 3500 records

Tags: ms-access, max

I have a single table in Access with a few thousand records. I have been asked to set up an automated delete query to keep only the 3500 most recent records. The only identified I have for the records is an AutoNumber ID field. However, when I try to setup a query using

Comment: Your question seems to have been cut off mid-sentence.

Comment: What you are looking for is to use `TOP` in your query.  You will need to elaborate on your question more to get useful answers out of the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your AutoNumber [ID] field is defined with its `New Values` property set to `Increment` (as opposed to `Random`) then a query to delete all but the 3500 most recent records would be

```
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT TOP 3500 ID 
        FROM YourTable
        ORDER BY ID DESC
    )
```